Adding a dashboard to a chart in react native
I have this D3 chart tutorial working in react native:
https://github.com/friyiajr/D3LineChartSample
If I wanted to take it to the next level and add a dashboard of highs and lows etc, beneath where the chart renders on the same screen in react native how would I go about it?
Cheers.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
